# C# http request add json object in the content

Tags: c#, json, http, httprequest

I'm making an http request post to an external api.  I am constructing a json object to add to the request body.  How can I check if the added body/content is correct before it is sent.

```
public async void TestAuthentication()
{
   var client = new HttpClient();

   var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
   {
       RequestUri = new Uri("http://test"),
       Method = HttpMethod.Post
   };
   var jsonObj = new
   {
       data = "eneAZDnJP/5B6r/X6RyAlP3J",
   };
   request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   
   var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: Generally if you can serialize it and then deserialize it back then you are good to go! Otherwise - well, it doesn't work in that case. Sometimes the serialization simply blows up. Your particular example, however, is created the json object by hand so it's up to you to make sure you did it right.

Comment: Store value of `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj)` in some string variable and observe it during debugging. and pass the same variable to the StringContent. If the serialization is happening as per the expectations then you can be sure that the same thing is being passed to the api as payload.

Comment: Your JSON will look like `{"data":"eneAZDnJP/5B6r/X6RyAlP3J"}`. You don't need to write code to check if it's valid or not.

Comment: I suggest to try restSharp

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure whether the serialization works as intended, you could give it a shot in LINQpad or dotnetfiddle.net. See [my example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VtePtT) that returns the JSON on the console. These tools are great for quick prototyping a method or a snippet, if you are not sure if a piece of code works as intended.

You could also check in [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), but that could be a bit of an overkill and works best if your connection if not encrypted (no HTTPS).

I personally tend to test code that calls some API the following way:

- Make the called URL parameterizable (via the classes constructor)
- If there is any variable data this data should be passed as the methods parameter(s)
- For your test start an HTTP server from your test fixture (read on testing with xUnit or NUnit if you don't know what this means)

  - I use [PeanutButter.SimpleHTTPServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeanutButter.SimpleHTTPServer) for that
- Pass the local IP to the class that accesses the API
- Check whether the HTTP server received the expected data

Whether or not this kind of code shall be tested (this way) may be debatable, but I found this way to work kind of good. I used to abstract the `HttpClient` class away, but IMHO I would not recommend this anymore, because if the class accesses the API (and does not do anything else, which is important), the HTTP access is the crucial part that shall be tested and not mocked.